# PDO fetchAll non object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why am I getting the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll()`.  I have looked over other issues with the same error but my code seems fine and it seems something to do with `$this->$db`and the `var_dump` returns `object(PDO)#2 (0) { }`

**index.php**

```
<?php  
    include('assets/misc/functions.php');

  $cars = new Cars(connection());

  $listAll = $cars->listCars();

  var_dump($listCars);
?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

function connection()
{
    try
    {
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'jzmcond_pdo1';
        $dbpass = '';
        $dbname = 'jzmcond_pdo1';

        $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $dbname.";", $dbuser, $dbpass);

        return $dbConnection;
    } catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

**Functions:**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

class Cars{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(PDO $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function listCars()
    {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `id` `rego` `engineSize` `type` `colour` `year` `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`")->execute();
        //return $query->fetchAll();

        var_dump($this->db); exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Add `$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: `var_dump($listCars);` should be `var_dump($listAll);`, since that's the only variable being used. Have you added error reporting from above? and maybe even `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: This `public function __construct(PDO $db){` I've seen people use `public function __construct(\PDO $db){` so that could also be another reason.

Comment: You also need commas for your columns "SELECT `id` `rego` `engineSize` `type` `colour` `year` `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`") - `"SELECT id, rego, engineSize, type, colour, year, additionalFeatures FROM cars"` and use backticks around them as you did. I've omitted the ticks due to commenting restrictions. That could just be the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- but no still the issue with `return $query->fetchAll();
`

Comment: You're welcome. So, about the error reporting/checking codes I've given you; have you implemented them in your files?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yup and i still get same error

Comment: Have you tried Rasclatt's answer? It was edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query syntax is wrong you didn't put in commas

change

```
SELECT `id` `rego` `engineSize` `type` `colour` `year` `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars
```

to

```
SELECT `id`, `rego`, `engineSize`, `type`, `colour`, `year`, `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`
```

You don't even need to prepare in this case, try this:

```
public function listCars()
{
    $query = "SELECT `id`, `rego`, `engineSize`, `type`, `colour`, `year`, `additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`";
    $stmt = $this->db->query($query);
    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
        exit();
    }
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $rows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  Still doesn't fix the issue with `return $query->fetchAll();
`

Comment: @JessMcKenzie check my update, if it does not work then your connection is bad

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. I have never done it the way you are doing it, but if I were going to try, this is what I would attempt...

```
<?php

function connection()
{
    try
    {
        $host   = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'jzmcond_pdo1';
        $dbpass = '';
        $dbname = 'jzmcond_pdo1';

        $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
        return $dbConnection;
    } catch (PDOException $error)
    {
        echo $error->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Classes**

```
class Cars{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function listCars()
    {
        // as @Meda suggested, commas in query, I never noticed that
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`rego`,`engineSize`,`type`,`colour`,`year`,`additionalFeatures` FROM `cars`");
        $query->execute();

        if($query->rowCount() > 0) {

                while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $_array[]   =   $result;
                    }
            }
        return  ($query->rowCount() > 0)? $_array:0;
    //  return  ($query->rowCount() > 0)? $query->fetchAll():0;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
include('config.php');
$db = connection();

 if($db !== false) {
      $CarDude = new Cars($db);
      $_list = $CarDude->listCars();
      print_r($_list);
     } ?>
```